# Qt Grid add cutting lines

Tags: qt, grid

Such like title I say,
The game.cpp:

```
#include "game.h"
#include "ui_game.h"
#include "qdebug.h"
Game::Game(QWidget *parent) :
   QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::Game)
{
    ui->setupUi(this); 
    QPalette palette;
    QPixmap pixmap(":/bgimg");
    palette.setBrush(this->backgroundRole(),QBrush(pixmap));
    this->setPalette(palette);
    InitLayout(6,6);
}

Game::~Game()
{
  delete ui;
}

void Game::InitLayout(int widthNum, int heightNum)
{
    ui->grid->setGeometry(QRect(0,0,1000,800));
   for(int i=0; i< heightNum;i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<widthNum;j++)
      {
          int total = i*10+j;
          QString s = QString::number(total);
          qDebug() << s << "\n";
          QLabel*item = new QLabel(this);
          //item->setText(s);
          ui->grid->addWidget(item,i+1,j+1);
       }
    }
}
```

And cell.cpp

```
#include "cell.h"
cell::cell(QWidget *parent):
QLabel(parent)
{
    this->setGeometry(0,0,20,20);
    QPixmap qpixmap(":/qizi");
    this->setPixmap(qpixmap);
}
```

I want to show the cutting line int Grid(You know that grid are divided into many cell by line). I can't find to property in Grid.

Comment: Please post the code as code, not as image

Comment: @demonplus It's Ok now?

Comment: It is much better thanks. What is cell in your code? If it is custom widget, why not add lines to it?

Comment: @demonplus I had add cell.cpp. Actually cell is a QLabel, because I inherit QLabel without doing anythings. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to draw lines between `QGridLayout` items? You display simple strings, maybe you should use any real **table**?

Comment: Yes, QTableWidget I think would be a solution http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html

Comment: @ilotXXI Yeah, I want to add some image by cell in QGridLayout. The problem is that I need some lines to separate those images in QGridLayout.

Comment: @demonplus Thank you！ Now I using a function "setCellWidget" in QTableWidget can solve my proble. : )

Comment: great, feel free to post your code as answer for future references

Comment: Way 1: use `QTableWidget` or `QTableView` with any model, customize view for desired appearance. Way 2 (hacky): as `QLabel`s are `QFrame`s, you can setup their frames and use it as grid lines. Way 3: draw lines by yourself in `paintEvent`. There are more complicated ways.

Comment: @ilotXXI I use way 1. I just want a quick way to deal with this problem. Anyway, Thanks a lot！

Comment: A `QGridLayout` is used to lay things out, not to draw anything. Layouts have no visual appearance by themselves.